# Enable Persist Extended Tracking in vuforia 6.2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to enable Persist Extended Tracking in vuforia 6.2.2, but all the solutions I got are not working as classes are not there in latest version.

How to enable it ?

Comment: ImageTargetBehaviour component exposes the Enable Extended boolean. Isn't it what you are after?

Comment: Its done...Thanks !